# Can not find the directory which is installing

Tags: python, django, macos

In my Mac, I use `sudo easy_install` the Django:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ sudo easy_install django
Password:
Searching for django
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Best match: Django 1.11.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/c0/31/4bffd9183066eea645430114419c30b030b599320da8246701b81c6a78d2/Django-1.11.2.tar.gz#md5=f089f1f86d25f2b78f6cf36478d4edd1
```

Maybe the Django is large to install, but I stuck in there too much time, so I want to use `su -du Django_directory` to look if it is installing.

But I use `whereis django`, I get nothing:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ whereis Django
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$
```

How can I find it in my Mac?

---

I use the `locate -b djnago`, get the below information:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:site-packages ldl$ locate -b djnago
locate: illegal option -- b
usage: locate [-0Scims] [-l limit] [-d database] pattern ...

default database: `/var/db/locate.database' or $LOCATE_PATH
```

Comment: what does which django returns?

Comment: @Exprator get nothing too.

Comment: locate -b django try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you go into the Finder -> Macintosh HD -> Library -> Python -> 2.x/3.x -> site-packages -> Django

If you can't see it try to show the hidden folders (cmd + shift + . )

I hope that is what you are looking for

p.s. what you can do and is working for me:
open terminal 1. `./manage.py shell` ->    2. `import django` -> 3 `django` and the terminal will show you the path as well

Comment: this way can find the directory. but why use whereis can not?

Comment: I have to be honest I never used "Whereis" and have absolutely no Idea why this is working or not. I added how I search for the location in the terminal.